# Why is my small scale A* pathing script skipping everything?

Tags: javascript, scope, path-finding, a-star

I'm writing an A* pathing script for a game set on a 7x7 grid of tiles with the player always in the middle (tile 24). Zeros are added as a visual and it's actually one array, not a 7x7 2D array.

```
[00,01,02,03,04,05,06]
[07,08,09,10,11,12,13]
[14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
[21,22,23,24,25,26,27]
[28,29,30,31,32,33,34]
[35,36,37,38,39,40,41]
[42,43,44,45,46,47,48]
```

The game is server-driven so the player uses relative coordinates. What that means is, if the player moves, tile[0] changes. The short version of that is the player will always move from tile 24, which is the center tile. The grid is hard coded in, but if I post it publicly I'll change the code a little; no problem.

The function should take a destination and find a good path from tile 24 to that square but what it actually does it return "undefined".

If I input 24 I want the game to output an array like this

```
[18,12,6]
```

Here's the code:

```js
z = 0;
function pathTo(goal){
    var createPath = function (goal){
        var createNode = function(i){
            this.id = i;
            this.g = Infinity;
            this.f = Infinity;
            this.parent = null;
            this.open = null;
        };
        
        this.nodes = Array(49);
        for(i=0;i<this.nodes.length;i++){
            this.nodes[i] = new createNode(i);
        }
        this.start = this.nodes[24];
        this.start.g = 0;
        this.currentNodeId = 24;
        this.goal = this.nodes[goal];
        this.bestPath = null;
    };//end createPath
    var getBestNeighbor = function(nodeId){
        z++
        if(z>50){throw z}debugger;
        console.log(nodeId);
        var getG = function(parentG){
            //here you can check the map for water, sand, and ruins penalties
            /*
                default = 1
                path = .9
                water = 3
            */

            return (parentG + 1);
        };
        var closeNode = function (node){
            node.open = false;
        };//end closeNode
        var getF = function(startId,endId,g){
            if(g>9){
                throw g;
            }
            var startX = startId % 7;
            var startY = (startId - startX) / 7;
            var endX = endId % 7;
            var endY = (endId - endX) / 7;
            var h = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((startX - endX) , 2 ) + Math.pow(( startY - endY ), 2 ) );
            console.log("Start.id:"+startId+"H:"+h+"  Start.id.g:"+g);
            return (h + g);
        };//end getF
        var tracePath = function(tracedNode){
            path.bestPath = [];
            while(tracedNode != path.start){
                path.bestPath.unshift(tracedNode.id);
                tracedNode = tracedNode.parent;
            }
            return path.bestPath;
        };//end tracePath
        var getNeighborNodeId = function(x,y,currentId){return currentId + (y*7) + x;};//end getNeighborNodeId
        if(path.bestPath === null){
            var neighborNode = {};
            var bestNode = {f: Infinity};
            if(nodeId == path.goal.id){//may need to pass path
                return tracePath(path.nodes[nodeId]);
            }else{
                for(x=-1;x<=1;x++){
                    for(y=-1;y<=1;y++){
                        var nnId = getNeighborNodeId(x,y,nodeId);
                        if(nnId==24){debugger}
                            if( ( (x!=0) && (y!=0) ) ||( (nnId>=0) && (nnId<=48))){
                                var neighborNode = path.nodes[nnId];
                                if(neighborNode.open === null){ neighborNode.open = true; }
                                if(neighborNode.open === true ){//don't check closed neighbors
                                    if(typeof neighborNode === "object"){
                                        neighborNode.parent = path.nodes[nodeId]
                                        debugger;
                                        neighborNode.g = getG(neighborNode.parent.g);
                                        neighborNode.f = getF(neighborNode.id , path.goal.id , neighborNode.g);
                                        if( neighborNode.f < bestNode.f){
                                            bestNode = neighborNode;
                                        }//endif
                                    }//endif
                                }//endif Note: if the node isn't null or true, it's false.
                            }
                    }//endfor
                }//endfor - Note: Here we should have the best neighbor
                if(bestNode.f == Infinity){
                    closeNode(path.nodes[nodeId]);//need escape for no possible path
                    return;
                }else{
                    //bestNode.parent = path.nodes[nodeId];
                    path.currentNodeId = bestNode.id;
                    getBestNeighbor(bestNode.id);
                }//endelse
            }//endelse
        }//endif
    };//end getBestNeighbor
    var path = new createPath(goal);
    while(path.bestPath === null){
        getBestNeighbor(path.currentNodeId);
    }//end while
    return path.bestPath;
}//end pathTo
console.log(pathTo(41));  //testing with 6
```

and a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jb4xtf3h/

It's my first time not just slapping globals everywhere, so it may have a scope issue I'm not familiar with.

Most likely my issue is in the getNeighborId function; I don't think I have anything declaring a good node's parent.

The problem is that it goes NW three times instead of NE three times. That probably means I have a mistake in the getBestNeighbor function where I'm reading a -1 as a 1.

Also I don't think I'm escaping the recursive function correctly.

For some reason, when I put in 41 it gets really confused. This either has to do with how I set G and H which are classically used in A* to record distance traveled on this path and the estimated distance remaining. Specifically the G number is wrong because it's taking bad steps for some reason.

Comment: I don't fully understand it, but it looks like `getNeighborNodeId(x,y,nodeId)` returns a negative number and there is no node with a negative number. In your logs, it goes `24`, `17`, `10`, `3`. I presume your algorithm is trying to go north and the next field north is out of bounds?

Comment: The negatives move north and west.  It goes into a function that converts the x/y into the number in the array id  so 0,0 goes through the function and comes out as 24 if the node being looked from is 24 if x=-1 on that loop and y=0 it will return 23 which is the tile west of 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code. I didn't implement walls or anything but I do show where you would do that. All you need to do is close all the nodes that are walls before you begin pathing and you can assign movement penalties if you want the AI to "know" to avoid water or sand.

I actually can't pin down a single problem but a major one was the way the statement:

```
if( ( (x!=0) && (y!=0) ) ||( (nnId>=0) && (nnId<=48))){
```

was changed to:

```
if( ( !(x==0 && y==0) && ( nnId>=0 && nnId<=48))){
```

The intent of this line was to prevent searching the tile you are standing on x,y = (0,0) and also to make sure that the neighbor you want to look at is on the grid (7x7 grid has 49 squares numbered 0-48)

What I was trying to say is "IF X & Y ARE BOTH NOT ZERO" apparently that actually makes it the same as an or statement so if either square was 0 it skipped it and tiles that needed that space were having problems since there were several directions that weren't working.

I hope that helps somebody if they need a nice simple pathing script  I tried really hard to make the code readable and I'm not the strongest coder in the world but a working A* script in 100 lines that I think is fairly easy to follow.  If you are reading this and you're not familiar with A* pathing what you might need to know is

H is your heuristic value it's an estimation of the remaining distance form a tile. In this code it's under the path object `path.nodes[array#].h`

G is the distance you've moved so far to get to that square `path.nodes[array#].g`.

F just adds h+g for the total value. [This pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) helped me write it.

```
var z =  0;
    function pathTo(goal){
        var createPath = function (goal){
            var createNode = function(i){
                this.id = i;
                this.g = Infinity;
                this.f = Infinity;
                this.parent = null;
                this.open = null;
            };
            
            this.nodes = Array(49);
            for(i=0;i<this.nodes.length;i++){
                this.nodes[i] = new createNode(i);
            }
            this.start = this.nodes[24];
            this.start.g = 0;
            this.currentNodeId = 24;
            this.goal = this.nodes[goal];
            this.bestPath = null;
        };//end createPath
        var path = new createPath(goal);
        var getBestNeighbor = function(nodeId){

            var getG = function(parentG){
                //here you can check the map for water, sand, and ruins penalties
                /*
                    default = 1
                    path = .9
                    water = 3
                */

                return (parentG + 1);
            };
            var closeNode = function (node){
                node.open = false;
            };//end closeNode
            var getF = function(startId,endId,g){
                var startX = startId % 7;
                var startY = (startId - startX) / 7;
                var endX = endId % 7;
                var endY = (endId - endX) / 7;
                var h = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((startX - endX) , 2 ) + Math.pow(( startY - endY ), 2 ) );
                return (h + g);
            };//end getF
            var tracePath = function(tracedNode){
                path.bestPath = [];
                while(tracedNode != path.start){
                    path.bestPath.unshift(tracedNode.id);
                    tracedNode = tracedNode.parent;
                }
                return path.bestPath;
            };//end tracePath
            var getNeighborNodeId = function(x,y,currentId){return currentId + (y*7) + x;};//end getNeighborNodeId
            debugger;
            z++
            if(z>50){throw z}
            if(path.bestPath === null){
                var neighborNode = {};
                var bestNode = {f: Infinity};
                if(nodeId == path.goal.id){//may need to pass path
                    return tracePath(path.nodes[nodeId]);
                }else{
                    for(y=-1;y<=1;y++){
                        for(x=-1;x<=1;x++){
                            var nnId = getNeighborNodeId(x,y,nodeId); 
                                if( ( !(x==0 && y==0) && ( nnId>=0 && nnId<=48))){
                                    var neighborNode = path.nodes[nnId];
                                    if(path.nodes[nodeId].parent!=neighborNode){
                                        if(neighborNode.open === null){ neighborNode.open = true; }
                                        if(neighborNode.open === true ){//don't check closed neighbors
                                            if(typeof neighborNode === "object"){
                                                neighborNode.parent = path.nodes[nodeId]
                                                neighborNode.g = getG(neighborNode.parent.g);
                                                neighborNode.f = getF(neighborNode.id , path.goal.id , neighborNode.g);
                                                if( neighborNode.f < bestNode.f){
                                                    bestNode = neighborNode;
                                                }//endif
                                            }//endif
                                        }
                                    }//endif Note: if the node isn't null or true, it's false.
                                }
                        }//endfor
                    }//endfor - Note: Here we should have the best neighbor
                    if(bestNode.f >= 50){
                        closeNode(path.nodes[nodeId]);//need escape for no possible path
                        return;
                    }else{
                        path.currentNodeId = bestNode.id;
                        getBestNeighbor(bestNode.id);
                    }//endelse
                }//endelse
            }//endif
        };//end getBestNeighbor
        while(path.bestPath === null){
            getBestNeighbor(path.currentNodeId);
        }//end while
        return path.bestPath;
    }//end pathTo
    myPath = pathTo(41);  //testing with 6
    console.log("path2:"+myPath);
```